# Extract a nested object from a dynamic column field in Mariadb

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I created a table with dynamic columns as following in MariaDb:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
 id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 product varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 data BLOB
);

INSERT INTO items (product, data) VALUES
 ('test_row', 
  COLUMN_CREATE('colour', 'blue', 
                'details',COLUMN_CREATE('key1','value1','key2','value2'))
 );
```

But I am not able to extract the nested object in a JSON format, when I execute the following query I get a some sort of binary output for details field:

```
SELECT product, COLUMN_GET(data, 'details' as CHAR(200)) AS Details
FROM items;
```

How can I decode this field data using a SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT `product`, COLUMN_JSON(COLUMN_GET(`data`, 'details' AS BINARY)) AS Details
FROM `items`;
```